# Pulling / selecting files by a specific timestamp, all files taken at 6:00am and 6:00pm

Tags: timestamp

Just wondering how to move files by a specific timestamp. I have a timelapse camera and I'm only concerned with files taken at 6am and 6pm. What is the best method to pull and move only these files out of a file containing many photos with random timestamps? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide more detail and an attempt at a solution. e.g. what platform / OS / language are you working with?

If you're just looking at a list of files on your computer, you can just sort them by date.

Comment: Using Windows, not any coding language but I would try it if it wasn't too complicated of a script. I can't simply sort. Is this something I can do with a batch command?

Essentially I have a folder containing 2000 files. Every day a file (images) is created in the folder at 6:00am and 6:00pm but there are also multiple files (images) created each day with random event times 2:37pm, 4:40am, etc. I need to isolate only the files with 6:00am or 6:00pm.